# Excel installed in different language vs OpenXml-Sdk cannot load the package

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I've been scratching my head around that one. So basically we produced an Excel file with lots of data a piece of software using Open-Xml SDK and send these files that will get modified by people around the world and send them back for us to import (using Open-Xml SDK again).

Most of the time it works, but a couple of times it did not.
The error message from Open-Xml SDK was very cryptic: The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing.

After investigating, I found out that if I saved the file with my own Excel application (Excel 2016) prior to import it, I could import the file. So I've extracted the zip file that is an xlsx and compare both.

The only thing that was different is the presence of this tag in the styles.xml file:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.fonts.knownfonts?view=openxml-2.8.1
Value of the tag is 1. My hypothesis, is that the existence of this tag is not the problem per say, but it's combined with the fact there are korean fonts that are saved (and used/referenced in worksheets) which end up causing open-xml to not be able to load the file.

So what I did is manually remove that tag from the styles.xml file and rezip to recreate the excel xlsx file and now, Open-Xml could import again even if the font, that I probably don't have on my system, were still used/referenced in the excel sheet)

I've tried to update Open-Xml SDK to 2.8.1, and then to 2.9.0 but still the same issue is happening. After asking question, the excel app that was used to save the excel and add this tag is installed in Korean and since it's a third party we have no control on what software version/language they used.

I also tried to play with compatibility markup options open loading the xml without any success.

My question would be is there any way to load an excel file having this tag using open-xml sdk without having to manually removed the tag or is this a bug of the OpenXML SDK that I should report?

Comment: What does the [Openxml SDK Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) say if you open the file in that and hit the Validate button?

Comment: I'd ask about / report this in the Open XML SDK section of GitHub. Sounds like a bug to me. Difficult to research what knownFonts is for, but it appears to be an extension to the original XL Open XML that allows for vertical positioning of string content, related to `dyDescent`  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926776(v=office.12).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd924712(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: The productivity tool cannot load the file: Cannot open the file: The specified file type is not supported. So I cannot hit the Validate button.

The manually fixed version can be open fine and Validate shows no error at all.
I do agree with Cindy, I think this deserve to be reported on GitHub Open XML SDK section.